# /src/firebase.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/anujgoyal/Desktop/reels/src'\?

Tags: firebase

image of the project and files

[image]

I am trying to import firebase in my react app, using the following syntax:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

But I am facing following issue:

> ./src/firebase.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/Desktop/reels/src'

commands i have ran on terminal:

```
npm i firebase
```

Also i have checked in the node modules firebase was there.

Comment: please help in finding the solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the ^9 version, so try this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
```